# How to pass additional RUSTFLAGS for specific binary?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

There is multiple binary build in my Cargo.toml:

```
[[bin]]
name = "a"
path = "src/a_main.rs"

[[bin]]
name = "b"
path = "src/b_main.rs"
```

How to add `-A dead_code` build key only for binary "b"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the same effect as `-A dead_code` by writing

```
#![allow(dead_code)]
```

at the start of `src/b_main.rs`.

Comment: Yes I know. How to to allow dead_code for all modules load from b_main, but not from a_main?

Comment: `#![allow(dead_code)]` should apply to all modules if you write it in the crate root (i.e. `b_main.rs`)...

Comment: Thanks. It works. Is there a way to specify this in the Cargo.toml?